# Split csv file with single quotes, double quotes or no quotes in c# using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

i have csv file in that split may either single quote,double quote or no quote using regular expression.

single quotes data like.
It may contains double quote or comma in single quotes.That need to be split by single quotes.

```
'name','Barcode','SecundaryKey','category','description','supplier','quantity','price','discount_price','short_name'
'eclipse 900-206 helping hands  iron holder -2.5x','30475','7crkvVHAFkVJu670c','Nu4m5WRJS','HNU6UFuR26nq','PtmI4DlZGfCk','iNHEvAMwIfVKfNFlVUOyEHDz','6977447822.90','7285957253.05','ybT8NOZB'
'bostitch 15 amp 7 1/4"" heavy circular saw blade','173924','BOYw88CXc12lau73Rylz','wMxwNtE','6qSJDZEFMYP8Q','l22xuvZ812b0ywe','SsvYZn0vqvTk8','8781804894.55','3277896.95','ULsAwUwU6b'
```

or Double quotes Data like.it may also contain comm inside double quotes.that need to split by Double quotes.

```
"name","Barcode","SecundaryKey","category","description","supplier","quantity","price","discountprice","shortname"
"qep glass, cutting,    blade","679976","8uDyHo8b","veJfgpim","nIxcT5ge2gIj","SmwQk","5qNOIvBmM3","2388127046.04","919372222.24","5VG2Yj4LgXop"
"rsr soldering station","892595","wflH6uknV7wb0M","NO72OTdjTSFx2","DLlpVgOyvqc","b8Bddyi","FctnER","3626684222.94","720238132.30","rZ2"
```

or without quotes that need to split by only comma.

```
SecundaryKey,Supplier,Name,Quantity,Barcode,IsTop,IsScannable,Category,Description,Price,DiscountPrice,Message,ShortName,ImageUrl
1001,Honig,Chinese Kippensoep 56 g,78 gram,,1,1,,none,1000,100,,Honig,http://www.janlinders.nl/system/html/8714700447c7.png
1002,Cote d'Or,Puur 200 g,200 gram,,1,0,,,9000,50,,,http://www.janlinders.nl/system/html/5410081w_1_bb-66c69fc6.png
```

Here Question is like these all three operation may be possible in CSV file because that is end user upload. how to handle these situation using regular expression in one.
i have tried but work for only single quote and double quote and without quote not three in one.
thanks.

Comment: just change your `"` to single and your code is already there to read it. like `yourcsv.Replace("\"", "'");`

Comment: but what about if single quote and possibility of parsing without quote csv rows

Comment: make `urstring = "'" + urcsv.replace(",","','") + "'";`

Comment: Can you use `string.split()` ?

Comment: Wouldn't string.Split(new[] { ',', '\"', '\'', }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) do the job?

Comment: ```.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim('\'', '\"'))```

Comment: i have used Regex.Split and string.split () method but it works on only one type means either single or double or no quotes but in my csv file user dependent how to differ all of them. and file is any type can split

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: https://github.com/phatcher/CsvReader

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using  `regular expressions` this `Regex.Split` does the job for you:

```
 var words = Regex.Split(text1, @"[''"",]").Where(w=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(w)).Select(w=>w.Trim());
```

It splits by comma or single quote or double quotes which is I believe what you want. It also removes empty results.

I hope it helps.